# pthread_create Memory Leaks

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, tcp, memory-leaks

I am trying to code a very basic multi-threaded TCP client server system and have managed to get the main functionality working as well as sorted any memory problems except for one.

When its time for the server to shutdown, I have it set up to receive and handle a SIGINT signal which will close the listen and connfd as well as do some arbitrary output.

The problem being that valgrind reports a memory leak on exit which it says is from pthread_create and threads being left active on exit. The leak is the size of 272 bytes for each connected user at the time.

[image: Valgrind output]

The code for the sig handler and main are as follows:

```
struct timeval t1, t2;
int connfd = 0;
int listenfd = 0;
pthread_t sniffer_thread;

static void SIGhandler(int sig, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *context)
{

    pthread_join(sniffer_thread, NULL);

    shutdown(connfd, SHUT_RDWR);
    shutdown(listenfd, SHUT_RDWR);

gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);

    double totalSeconds = (double) (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1000000 + (double) (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) ;

    int seconds = ((int)totalSeconds % 60);
    int minutes = ((int)totalSeconds % 3600) / 60;
    int hours = ((int)totalSeconds % 86400) / 3600;
    int days = ((int)totalSeconds % (86400 * 30)) / 86400;

    printf("\n\nServer shutdown request received");
    printf ("\nTotal server up time = %d days %d hours %d minutes and %d seconds\n\n",days, hours ,minutes , seconds);

    close(connfd);
    close(listenfd);


exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


int main(void)
{

    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);

struct sigaction act;

memset(&act, '\0', sizeof(act));

// this is a pointer to a function
act.sa_sigaction = &SIGhandler;

// the SA_SIGINFO flag tells sigaction() to use the sa_sigaction field, not sa_handler
act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;

if (sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL) == -1) {
perror("sigaction");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
socklen_t socksize = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(50001);

bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

if (listen(listenfd, 10) == -1) {
perror("Failed to listen");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
// end socket setup

//Accept and incoming connection
puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
while (1) {
printf("Waiting for a client to connect...\n\n");
connfd =
    accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &socksize);

printf("\n\nConnection established with: %s\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr));
printf("%s is connected on socket:  %d\n",inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr),connfd);


    // third parameter is a pointer to the thread function, fourth is its actual parameter
if (pthread_create
    (&sniffer_thread, NULL, client_handler,
     (void *) &connfd) < 0) {
    perror("could not create thread");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


printf("Handler assigned\n\n");
}

// never reached...
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
} // end main()
```

The client handler code is:

```
// thread function - one instance of each for each connected client
void *client_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
//Get the socket descriptor
int connfd = *(int *) socket_desc;

send_conConfirm(connfd);


char choice[8];

do {
            get_menu_choice(connfd,choice);
            switch (*choice) {
            case '1':
                printf("Executing IP/ID return for socket: %d\n",connfd);
            send_studentID(connfd);
        break;
            case '2':
                printf("Executing server time return for socket: %d\n",connfd);
            send_serverTime(connfd);
        break;
            case '3':
                printf("Executing sys info return for socket: %d\n",connfd);
            send_uname(connfd);
        break;
            case '4':
                printf("Executing file list return for socket: %d\n",connfd);
            send_filenames(connfd,choice);
        break;
            case '5':
            send_filenames(connfd,choice);
        break;
            case '6':
                printf("Disconection choice on socket: %d\n",connfd);
        break;
            default:
            printf("Client on socket %d has been disconnected\n", connfd);
                goto jump;
        break;
        }
} while (*choice != '6' );



    jump: //jump for goto statement


shutdown(connfd, SHUT_RDWR);
close(connfd);

printf("Thread %lu exiting\n", (unsigned long) pthread_self());

return 0;
}  // end client_handler()
```

I have tried many different ways including detaching the threads upon completion but always end up with this memory leak. Occasional the memory leak will occur even if the client has only connected and the server ends and other times it will only occur if the client connects and interacts with the server.

Comment: Could you share us the code of  `client_handler` function?

Comment: @JorgeOmarMedra Edited it to include the client_handler for you now.

Comment: there are LOTS of problems with the code, beyond the one you specifically ask about.  I.E. the returned value from `socket()` is not checked, calling `exit()` without cleaning up, after `pthread_detach()` the main thread cannot use `pthread_join()`  'choice' is 8 characters, but 'switch' can only handle a single 'int' value, not a string.  etc etc etc

Comment: regarding: `goto jump;`  This is a very bad idea, instead, just set 'choice', to 6.   NOTE: 'choice' is an array, not a pointer to an array, so this: `switch (*choice) {` should be: `switch( choice )`  and 'choice' should be a 'int' or a single char.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces. 2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.

Comment: there are MANY functions that should not be called in a signal handler.  The posted code is calling several of those functions inside the signal handler.  Suggest the signal handler just set a flag and the main loop of the program be checking that flag.

Comment: the posted code can only handle a single client at a time.  (even though the call to `listen()` allows for up to 10 clients at a time)  Suggest using a 'thread pool' as calls to `pthread_create()` and `pthread_exit()` are very expensive

Comment: Suggest the code to call `accept()` be, itself, a thread, then the main thread can be checking for some flag being set by the signal handler.  The main thread needs to be able to tell all the 'sub' threads to exit.  Then it needs to call `pthread_join()` for every 'sub' thread.  This is usually done be keeping an array of thread IDs and calling `pthread_join()` for each of those IDs, in a loop

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a join before the end of your while loop, rather than in your signal catching function

I would recommend looking through the last few sections of this guide, a few problems with your code that they handle are:

- joining the threads so that threads dont stay open because you are using
  threading,
- your connfd can be overwritten (as it exists in same
  memory space across different threads)
- adjusting your while loop to
  run only while the connection is open (changing it to be on the
  return of accept)

http://www.binarytides.com/socket-programming-c-linux-tutorial/

Comment: I went and implemented the suggests and unfortunetly the 272 bytes are still being lost! I went ahead and gave the suggested tutorial a full implement and even that has the same 272 bytes lost on sigint exit

Comment: @DarylVaDazzleMcAllister,  when running valgrind, always set it to ignore problems found in system/library functions

Comment: the linked tutorial has a few problem.  1) outputs most error messages to `stdout` rather than `stderr`  2) fails to pass the socket to `close()` in the client handler code, before passing the socket to `free()`.  3) has a comment about calling `pthread_join()`, but never actually calls that function.  4) the threads should call `pthread_exit()` as a better choice than `return` 5) fails to check the returned value from `listen()`  6) the loop extracting the IP address comments that it will use the first one but actually uses the last one

Comment: cont: 7) the 'connection_handler()` function should loop until a return from `read()` is 0, (meaning the client has disconnected) then exit the loop 8) this statement: `new_sock = malloc(1);` doesn't allocate enough room.  it should be: `new_sock = malloc( sizeof( int ) );`  and then check that the allocation was successful:  `if( !new_sock ) { perror( "malloc failed"; pthread_exit( NULL ); } 8) the call to `listen()` states that three connections can be active at once, so the `sniffer_thread` should be an array of 3, with related changes, so main thread can call `pthread_join()` (cont)

Comment: (cont) in a loop, so it does not exit until all threads have exited.